# SqlDelight: "No table found with name"

Tags: android, android-studio, sqldelight

I am having trouble with what seems like to be with the `SqlDelight` intellij plugin. I am trying to write the migrations in one place and not use `CREATE` statements at all inside the `.sq` files.

This is my setup:

`src/main/sqldelight`:

```
├── com
│   └── wtf
│       └── errorrepro
│           └── database
│               └── one.sq
├── migration
│   └── v1.sqm
└── schema
```

`v1.sqm`

```
CREATE TABLE something(
    id INTEGER
);
```

`one.sq`

Here is the issue I am getting inside the editor. No code table-related code hinting is available here, `generate` menu is also blank in this file.

```
what:
SELECT * FROM something;
              ^^^^^^^^^
              No table found with name something
```

`build.gradle`

I am only showing here the relevant `sqldelight` config, I am using version `1.5.3` (gradle plugin, intellij plugin and dependency are all on the same version).

```
...

sqldelight {
    MyDatabase {
        packageName = "com.wtf.errorrepro.database"
        deriveSchemaFromMigrations = true
        verifyMigrations = true
    }
}

...
```

---

If I run any of the `gradle` commands, like `generateDebugMyDatabaseInterface`, the proper `queries` are generated. So I do not understand why the editor shows the 'No table found with name' error.

I have reinstalled the plugin, updated gradle, did a clean rebuild, invalidated sources ... Nothing seems to solve this.

---

Edit:

It is even weirder that in case I create a totally separate project `Kotlin` + `Groovy Gradle` and set up `SqlDelight` there, then the code navigation works well. It is only if I create this setup in an Android project (it can be entirely new) when the navigation fails.

Comment: But isn't this what the `deriveSchemaFromMigrations` is for? From the docs: https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/jvm_h2/gradle/ `Whether or not to use .sqm files as the source of truth for the schema`

Comment: Haven't worked with this option, so can't help you here. There's more chances to get an answer in [Kotlin slack](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up), **#squarelibraries** channel