# Attempting to alter something that is not a table, when do a migration with SqlDelight

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I'm blocking on this issue, i have a file **.sqm** to migrate my database from version 1 to version 2 as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN name TEXT DEFAULT "";
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN phoneNumber TEXT DEFAULT "";
```

This file is in the same directory of **.db** files, the migration is success in case I omit the "**[verifyMigration](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/multiplatform_sqlite/gradle/)**" in the sqldelight configuration (**gradle**.kts) as follow, when i put it give me the following error:
**Attempting to alter something that is not a table.
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN driverName TEXT DEFAULT ""**

My gradle config:

```
sqldelight {
    database("MyDataBase") {
        packageName = "com.xx"
        sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
        schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/commonMain/sqldelight/com/xx")
         verifyMigrations = true
    }
}
```

[It seems to be the same issue as this posted question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249315/sqldelight-no-table-found-with-name)

I have reinstalled the plugin, updated gradle, did a clean rebuild, invalidated sources ... Nothing seems to solve this.